# How to download an image from URL in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, download

In my Asp.net MVC I had used following code when the image file kept in an actual folder structure.

```
public FileResult DownloadFile(string imageName)
        {
            string fullPath = this.GetFullPath(imageName);
            string contentType = " image/pjpeg";

            return new FilePathResult(fullPath, contentType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = imageName
            };
        }
```

However now we have moved images to Azure Blob, And how can we download the image from there. Since FilePathResult dint work out we tried using the following code.

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string imgName)
        {            
            string fullPath = imgName;            
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConString"));
            CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = client.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobReference"]);

            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(imgName);

            return Redirect(blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        }
```

However the files are not downloading, instead it opens in a new window, Please guide me to download the file instead of opening in the new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two ways by which you can accomplish this thing:

**1. Assuming you would always want the file to be downloaded**

If you want the file to be always downloaded, you can set the `Content-Disposition` property of the blob as `attachment; filename=yourdesiredfilename`. In this case `blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri` will always force the file to download.

**2. Assuming you want the flexibility of both downloading the file sometimes and opening the file in the browser**

In this case, you could create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) on the blob and specify `Content-Disposition` header as a part of SAS. Here's the sample code to do so:

```
        CloudStorageAccount acc = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("<accountname>", "<accountKey>"), true);
        var client = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = client.GetContainerReference("<containername>");
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("<imagename.png>");
        var sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
        }, new SharedAccessBlobHeaders()
        {
            ContentDisposition = "attachment;filename=<imagename.png>",
        });
        var blobUrl = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sasToken;
        Redirect(blobUrl);
```

My recommendation would be to go with #2 as it gives you more security + you will be able to share blobs from private blob containers as well.

Comment: Dear Gaurav, Thanks for helping out when Itry wih the code I end up getting the erro : <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code> 
  <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:602cbaa4-c4cc-445b-84aa-b02fd0c5932c Time:2014-05-28T07:18:51.7078236Z</Message> 
  <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2014-05-28T08:18:47Z  Any Idea, how to solve it

Comment: I tried it with the latest version of storage client library and it works fine. Will it be possible for you to share the code (obviosuly take out the account name/key and other sensitive information)? Also please check if the clock on your computer is not off. I have seen this kind of error coming in because of that or because of incorrect account key.

Comment: Thanks lot Gaurav, I replaced the line "CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(imgName);" with "ICloudBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(imgName);" its working fine.

Comment: Hmmm...that's weird. I would not recommend doing this simply because `GetBlobReferenceFromServer` actually makes a call to storage service and because it's a network call, it may fail. Plus you don't really need to do this to create a SAS URL.

Comment: Oky then let me try with the previous code. Not sure what is the problem.